# Draw a line over a window inside a canvas in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas

I am developing a game using Python Tkinter and ran into a problem. I am creating a window of a label inside of my canvas and I want to draw a line over it, however the line is drawn behind the label.

Here is some sample code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canv = tk.Canvas(root, width = 200, height = 200)
canv.pack()

text = tk.Label(root, text = "some text")
canv.create_window(100, 100, window = text)
canv.create_line(0, 0, 200, 200, width = 3, fill = "#00ff00")

root.mainloop()
```

The result is a 200x200 canvas with a label in the middle, and the line is drawn on the canvas and behind the label.
Is there a way to draw the line over the label instead of behind it?

Note: it is very important that the label stays a label, the label is the important part not the text.

Comment: Maybe give your Label an image that has the plain text and reconfigure the Label with another image of text with a line over it when you need to show a drawn line across the Label ??? could make your own image using a graphics app. Or rather than reconfigure since it is Canvas remove the plain text Label and create another in the same place with your line drawn image ??? – 
InhirCode
19 mins ago

Comment: Why is it important that the "label stays a label"? What is it about a Label that you need to do, that you can't do with a canvas text item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot draw lines over window objects on a canvas. That is a fundamental limitation of the canvas.

This is what the [canonical documentation](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M15) says:

*The items in a canvas are ordered for purposes of display, with the first item in the display list being displayed first, followed by the next item in the list, and so on. Items later in the display list obscure those that are earlier in the display list and are sometimes referred to as being “on top” of earlier items. When a new item is created it is placed at the end of the display list, on top of everything else. Widget commands may be used to re-arrange the order of the display list.*

***Window items are an exception to the above rules. The underlying window systems require them always to be drawn on top of other items.** In addition, the stacking order of window items is not affected by any of the canvas widget commands; you must use the Tk raise command and lower command instead.*

Comment: That's a bummer. Is there maybe an alternative?

Comment: @ilanlansh: that depends on what you're actually trying to accomplish. Perhaps you could explain more about why you need to draw lines over labels, and why it has to be labels rather than text elements on the canvas.