# How to show overlapped Label and text simultaneously in Canvas by Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, frame

I want to show overlapped Label and text simultaneously in Canvas by Tkinter.
Here are my data.

```
import tkinter as tk  # python 3

def populate(frame):
    '''Put in some fake data'''
    for row in range(100):
        tk.Label(frame, text="%s" % row, width=3, borderwidth="1", bg="red",
                 relief="solid").grid(row=row, column=0)
        t="this is the second column for row %s" %row
        tk.Label(frame, text=t,bg="pink").grid(row=2*row, column=1)

def onFrameConfigure(canvas):
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, borderwidth=0,bg="blue")
frame = tk.Frame(canvas,bg="yellow")
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor="nw")
frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas: onFrameConfigure(canvas))
populate(frame)
canvas.create_text(250,300,text="10kV/35kV")

root.mainloop()
```

But now the overlapped text ("10kV/35kV") is hidden,as shown in this figure.

[image: 1]

Is there any way to show the whole text even if it is overlapped with labels?

Comment: Similar issue as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71197371/draw-a-line-over-a-window-inside-a-canvas-in-tkinter).  Basically you cannot put a text item over tkinter widget in a canvas.

Comment: You cannot place a text item over a canvas window item but you can place canvas window items over other window items. The limitation is that the order in which window items are created is static, so 'canvas.lift' and 'canvas.lower' will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

This code demonstrates how to overlay `winA` with `winB`.

Replace `canvas.create_text(250,300,text="10kV/35kV")` with this snippet.

```py
message = tk.Label(canvas, text = "10kV/35kV", bg = 'blue', fg = 'white')
winB = canvas.create_window(80, 21, window = message, anchor = tk.NW)
```